# Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: php, laravel, null

Всем привет, пишу на Laravel неделю, я новичок! Связался с ошибкой "Attempt to read property "id" on null". Помогите решить Пожалуйста!!! По идеи нужно правильно провести путь, но я пытался, ничего не вышло!

**Cheme**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
};
```

**CategoryComponent**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Cart;
use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryComponent extends Component
{

    public $sorting;
    public $pagesize;
    public $category_slug;

    
    public function mount($category_slug)
    {
        $this->sorting = "default";
        $this->pagesize = 12;
        $this->category_slug = $category_slug;
    }
    public function store($product_id,$product_name,$product_price)
    {
        Cart::add($product_id,$product_name,1,$product_price)->associate('App\Models\Product');
        session()->flash('success_message','Item added in Cart');
        return redirect()->route('product.cart');
    }
    use WithPagination;
    public function render()
    {
        $category = Category::where('slug',$this->category_slug)->first();
        $category_id = $category->id;
        $category_name = $category->name;
        if($this->sorting=='data')
        {
            $products = Product::where('category_id',$category_id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
        }
        else if ($this->sorting=='price')
        {
            $products = Product::where('category_id',$category_id)->orderBy('regular_price','ASC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
        }
        else if ($this->sorting=='price-desc')
        {
            $products = Product::where('category_id',$category_id)->orderBy('regular_price','DESC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
        }
        else
        {
            $products = Product::where('category_id',$category_id)->paginate($this->pagesize);
        }
        $categories = Category::all();
        $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(4)->get();

        return view('livewire.category-component',['products'=>$products,'categories'=>$categories,'category_name'=>$category_name])->layout("layouts.base");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

````
    <main id="main" class="main-site left-sidebar">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="wrap-breadcrumb">
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-link"><a href="/" class="link">home</a></li>
                    <li class="item-link"><span>Product Categories</span></li>
                    <li class="item-link"><span>{{$category_name}}</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 main-content-area">

                    <div class="banner-shop">
                        <a href="#" class="banner-link">
                            <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/shop-banner.jpg') }}" alt=""></figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-shop-control">

                        <h1 class="shop-title">{{$category_name}}</h1>

                        <div class="wrap-right">

                            <div class="sort-item orderby ">
                                <select name="orderby" class="use-chosen" wire:model="sorting">
                                    <option value="default" selected="selected">Default sorting</option>
                                    <option value="date">Sort by newness</option>
                                    <option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option>
                                    <option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sort-item product-per-page">
                                <select name="post-per-page" class="use-chosen" wire:model="pagesize">
                                    <option value="12" selected="selected">12 per page</option>
                                    <option value="16">16 per page</option>
                                    <option value="18">18 per page</option>
                                    <option value="21">21 per page</option>
                                    <option value="24">24 per page</option>
                                    <option value="30">30 per page</option>
                                    <option value="32">32 per page</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="change-display-mode">
                                <a href="#" class="grid-mode display-mode active"><i class="fa fa-th"></i>Grid</a>
                                <a href="list.html" class="list-mode display-mode"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>List</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end wrap shop control-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="product-list grid-products equal-container">
                            @foreach ($products as $product)
                            
                            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                                <div class="product product-style-3 equal-elem ">
                                    <div class="product-thumnail">
                                        <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="T-Shirt Raw Hem Organic Boro Constrast Denim">
                                            <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/products') }}/{{$product->image}}" alt="{{$product->name}}"></figure>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-info">
                                        <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" class="product-name"><span>{{$product->name}}</span></a>
                                        <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">{{$product->regular_price}}</span></div>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart" wire:click.prevent="store({{$product->id}},'{{$product->name}}',{{$product->regular_price}})">Add To Cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-pagination-info">
                        {{$products->links()}}
                        {{-- <ul class="page-numbers">
                            <li><span class="page-number-item current" >1</span></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item" href="#" >2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item" href="#" >3</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item next-link" href="#" >Next</a></li>
                        </ul> --}}
                        <p class="result-count">Showing 1-8 of 12 result</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end main products area-->

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sitebar">
                    <div class="widget mercado-widget categories-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">All Categories</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-category">
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <li class="category-item">
                                    <a href="{{route('product-category',['category_slug'=>$category->slug])}}" class="cate-link">{{$category->name}}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Categories widget-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget brand-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Brand</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style vertical-list list-limited" data-show="6">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link active" href="#">Fashion Clothings</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Laptop Batteries</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Printer & Ink</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">CPUs & Prosecsors</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Sound & Speaker</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Shop Smartphone & Tablets</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Printer & Ink</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">CPUs & Prosecsors</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Sound & Speaker</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Shop Smartphone & Tablets</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a data-label='Show less<i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>' class="btn-control control-show-more" href="#">Show more<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- brand widget-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget price-filter">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Price</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <div id="slider-range"></div>
                            <p>
                                <label for="amount">Price:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
                                <button class="filter-submit">Filter</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Price-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Color</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style vertical-list has-count-index">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Red <span>(217)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Yellow <span>(179)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Black <span>(79)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Blue <span>(283)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Grey <span>(116)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Pink <span>(29)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Color -->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Size</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style inline-round ">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link active" href="#">s</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">M</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">l</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">xl</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="widget-banner">
                                <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/size-banner-widget.jpg') }}" width="270" height="331" alt=""></figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Size -->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget widget-product">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Popular Products</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="products">
                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/products/digital_01.jpg') }}" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/products/digital_17.jpg') }}" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/products/digital_18.jpg') }}" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/products/digital_20.jpg') }}" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- brand widget-->

                </div><!--end sitebar-->

            </div><!--end row-->

        </div><!--end container-->

    </main>
    <!--main area-->
```[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptrbF.png
````

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: см. как отладить код и номер строки.. ↑↑↑   ошибка говорит что ты пытаешься обратиться к свойству объекта, а сам объект null

Comment: 1.  У тебя сортировка по продуктам никогда не будет работать, зачем ты пишешь получение продуктов в ифах, если потом все равно получаешь другие продукты?

2. Эта ошибка возникает когда ты пытаешься получить какое-то свойства у переменной null и скорее всего это происходит в категориях когда нет категории с таким slug
$category_id = $category->id;

Comment: @Ricco381 https://youtu.be/LJ5H3ec3mrU 11:23, но у него же так написано и всё работает!

Comment: @quelle у него написано не так, пересмотри еще раз видео только внимательно  
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(4)->get(); эта строчка делает твои ифы бесполезным кодом!